# Widly varying results when measuring transistor hFE

Tags: transistors

I have the following circuit (see below) which I'm using to measure hFE of BC550 and BC560.

As a test, I measured the hFE of 5 transistors yesterday and today. Today's results are easily 3x of yesterday's.

Would using an LCR meter provide a more reliable results?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you measuring the same transistors, at the same temperature? You would expect a range of 3x across a batch of the same transistor type.

Comment: Can you please mention the actual hFE measured ? Did you use a battery  and replaced it between "yesterday" and "today" ? The BCxxx transistors usually have current gain in a rough range of 100-500. Unless you have "A/B/C" suffix hFE-binned parts, a range of 3 is normal. The binned ones should be probably tighter than a 3x range.